# BigDecimal setScale being ignored?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
    setValue(BigDecimal value)
    {
      this.value=value;
      this.value.setScale(8, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
    }

    BigDecimal getValue()
    {
       return value;
    }

   setValue(0.0314159*Math.random());
```

I have no idea why, but getValue() is producing BigDecimals with many many more decimal places than 8.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

If you read the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int)), you will see that setScale returns a new BigDecimal

Comment: More to the point, all BigDecimal methods do the same, that mutate the original object.  BigDecimals are immutable, and don't ever change.